# Can gdalwarp reproject from ESPG:4326 (WGS84) to UTM?

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system

I've a GeoTIFF image in ESPG:4326 (WGS84) and when I try with gdalwarp to reproject to UTM, it has problem

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' -of GTIFF test.tif test1.tif
```

ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.

Here is the information of this TIFF file

```
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-91.773493181429174,29.826496486509463)
Pixel Size = (0.001452475638877,-0.001452475638877)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2015:02:02 14:54:05
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IDL TIFF file
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -91.7734932,  29.8264965) ( 91d46'24.58"W, 29d49'35.39"N)
Lower Left  ( -91.7734932,  29.4982370) ( 91d46'24.58"W, 29d29'53.65"N)
Upper Right ( -91.3973020,  29.8264965) ( 91d23'50.29"W, 29d49'35.39"N)
Lower Right ( -91.3973020,  29.4982370) ( 91d23'50.29"W, 29d29'53.65"N)
Center      ( -91.5853976,  29.6623667) ( 91d35' 7.43"W, 29d39'44.52"N)
Band 1 Block=259x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=259x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=259x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: I see the problem is due to I try to reproject this image outside of its UTM zone then gdalwarp cannot do this.

Answer (score 5):

Try with other zone it has no problem, I guess GDAL cannot wrap it outside.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' test.tif test_utm1.tif
```

Comment: It can reproject to neighbouring UTM zones, but not 100° of longitude away, If you need a wide spanning projection, you have to switch from transverse mertacor to a Lambert or Albers projection.